# Is data distributed as a Gaussian?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution

I know there are methods to check whatever the observed data DOES NOT follow a Normal distribution. I'm thinking about chi-square test, Anderson test etc.

Is there any function/test/metric which says how Gaussian-like is the data distribution?

Thanks

Comment: Can you define what you mean by 'how Gaussian-like'?

Comment: [Is the map the territory?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation)

Comment: How about normalising and comparing the empirical cdf with the cdf of Gaussian?

Comment: @Łukasz That is precisely what the QQ plot suggested in Silverio's answer will do.  The related hypothesis test is the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test of distribution.

Comment: @whuber I answered to Hunaphu about the Kolmogorov test, expressing my dubts

Comment: The KS test *statistic* is a measure of departure from Normality.  Other distributional tests provide other statistics: they all measure departures from Normality differently, with some of them weighting the tails more or less heavily than the others.  I don't understand why you are challenging @Hunaphu, though: you explicitly ask for a "test" in the last line.

Comment: @marcodena: Re your comments under a now-deleted answer, the KS test statistic indeed has a different distribution when the parameters of the null-hypothesis Gaussian distribution are estimated from the same data. The KS test used in this case is often called the Lilliefors test, after the chap who first tabulated that distribution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Departures from the assumption of normality are not easy to quantify since they are not uniquely defined. For instance, the data may present departures from normality in terms of asymmetry, heavier tails, lighter tails, multimodality, et cetera.

The use of [hypothesis tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing) does not provide evidence in favour of a hypothesis, for philosophical reasons.

There are some visual tools that you can use to see how close to normality your sample is, such as QQ-plots (against normal quantiles).

If you have a clue about the type of departure your data present (you can take a look at their histogram en 1-D), then you can try to fit a model that contains the normal distribution as a particular case, and see whether this is close to the normal distribution or not.  For instance, if your data seem to have heavier tails than normal and asymmetry, you could use some sort of skew-t distribution to fit your data ([or some other distribution](http://statistics.open.ac.uk/802576CB00593013/(httpInfoFiles)/FE2EE03EDE61AB8E80257C700040D68E/$file/review.pdf) that contain the normal distribution as a limit case or a particular case). Then, take a look at the estimators of the degrees of freedom and the skewness parameter to see whether they indicate departures from the assumption of normality (e.g. if the estimator of the skewness parameter is very close to zero (or the one that reduces the model to symmetry) and the estimator of the degrees of freedom is large, then the data should look close to normal). You can also fit a normal model and calculate some distance/divergence between the flexible fitted model and the normal fitted model (e.g. Kullback–Liebler divergence, ...)

Comment: You talked about visual tests. What about the statistical ones? I need to test this for A LOT of different cases.
Thankkks

Comment: Marcodena, you can quantify the visual test by using the correlation coefficient of the coordinates of the normal qq-plot.  That will allow you to automate the process.  See [Filliben (1975)](http://www.claremontmckenna.edu/pages/faculty/MONeill/Math152/Handouts/filliben.pdf)

Comment: @marcodena If I had to do this multiple times, I would go for a likelihood ratio test (I am assuming the use of a model that contains the normal one) of the flexible model vs. the normal model. This should be doable and this is a UMPT.

Comment: @Silverio flexible model? Anyway I don't have the "normal one". Sorry, I'm bothering you :)

Answer (score 0):

The Jarque-Bera test checks for kurtosis and skew that match the normal distribution.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jarque%E2%80%93Bera_test

Comment: The Wikipedia article on the Normal distribution lists several tests for Normality: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Normality_tests